# Publisher 2007 Hangs on Microsoft Terminal Server 2003 Enterprise

Tags: terminal-server, microsoft-office

I have looked many places for the answer to this question and server fault looks like a great place to look some more.

We run in an environment which is completely thin-client to fat-server setup. All applications for all users are run on our server. Almost all applications work just like you would expect with the exception of Publisher 2007. I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2007 installed. Every couple of days I notice one of the four processors is completely pegged. I open taskman and mspub.exe has it run into the ground. It does not happen all of the time, and it tends to correlate with mail merges out of Excel, although not always.

Things I know:

1. It can happen to more than one user, at the same time
2. The mail merge when it tends to happen has long been over
3. Given a period of time mspub will still not recover. I have let it run for two or three days hoping it might stop.
4. The user does not "sense" the application is locked-up. Even though it has the processor pegged it still responds to user input and closes by taskman or the close button from the user without problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The next time it happens, try to find out what activity is occuring in the mspub.exe process.

Use [Microsoft/Sysinternal's Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see the resources the process is accessing or trying to access. Maybe you can deduce the problem from what you are seeing there.